# When does a brick wall become a dead end?

Tags: brick, wall, dead, end, quit

This may be more of a philosophical question than a genealogical research one, but I am wondering if, and/or at what point, does a brick wall become a dead end?

For example: I have an early American ancestor for whom I cannot find a family of origin, and I've been looking for 30 years. He has many descendant researchers, including one famous professional genealogist, and none of us can even verify his place of birth with any certainty.

I've researched, located and viewed all of the possible records (paper and digital) that could tell me more about him, and I've researched his FAN club. We have theories and hypotheses, but I fear there is no way to confirm or deny them. When is it time to call time?

Answer (score 4):

I think it's better to say that, at some point, you call "time out" and let the family come back to it later.

In my own case, we had no idea where in Germany my great-great-grandfather had immigrated from.  There were no records.  My great-aunt had tried in the 1960's, and gave up.  My aunt tried in the 1970's, but also hit a wall.  I finally was able to break the wall down, but it took the MUCH easier access to records that came with them being digitized, plus lucky DNA testing.  Even then, it wasn't until some church records from eastern Germany were digitized in 2015 that I was able to confirm the DNA connections.  After much additional work digging through state archives, I have that line back to the early 1500s.

My takeaway has been, just keep adding anything you find, no matter how small the detail.  Even if you don't break that wall down, someone else down the road might.  The work the prior generations had done - and written down! - was invaluable to my finally breaking down that wall.  But they didn't have DNA to work with, nor would they have been able to access a physical church book located in then East Germany.

I still have 6 immigrant ancestors whom I've not been able to solve, but even if I don't, perhaps a future generation will.  So I pick away at them, from time to time, but I don't obsess over them.  Thus, a 'time out', rather than ever just entirely quitting trying.